# heroku nodejs app push files to another heroku nodejs app through git remote

Tags: git, node.js, heroku

I have two nodejs apps on heroku.
I need one of my apps to change the files of the other's.
I have a git url for the destination app.
In other words I have files in the memory of a nodejs app. I need to push them to a git url.
Something like this nodejs git-stream module, but that doesnt work.

pls..

Answer (score 0):

I would not definetely recommend using of git for this purpose. If your app changes others files and you want to push, entire application that has the changed files just restarts and it takes a long time in heroku because of downloading modules from external. Instead, implement a secure file upload mechanism that only your server can connect, and stream the file via http to that server.

Comment: The problem is the destination heroku app receives the files, but it cant write to its own app directory overwriting its own files??...